# jq - decode json value in flow

Tags: json, apache, jq

I am need to decode the authorization value from apache in flow and replace the value with the username , returning the modified json.

original Json:

```
{ "time":"2022-04-07T12:53:39.302+0300", 
.... 
"user":"Basic c2RwC2ZhcmZZc3Q6c2RfX2ZhcmVhz3Q=" }
```

I want to get json:

```
{ "time":"2022-04-07T12:53:39.302+0300", 
.... 
"user":"<login>" }
```

Decoded value here is `<username>:<password>`

I'm trying to use the `jq` utility for this

```
stdin> | jq -r  '.user | gsub ("Basic "; "") | @base64d | gsub ("^.*:"; "")'
```

But `jq` returns the value itself, not the modified json.
Also, I get an error if json value (`user`) isn't base64
`"user":"-"`

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): string ("-") is not valid base64 data
```

How can I get the full modified json and avoid modification if the user value does not contain "Basic" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if ... then ... else ... end` to implement different behaviours depending  on a value.

```sh
jq '.user |= if startswith("Basic ")
             then .[6:] | @base64d
             else . end
  ' file.json
```

Comment: Thanks, its work.
Btw, how I can setup multiple strings in startswith?
I noticed, some values comes with `basic`, not `Basic` at the beginning

Comment: You can use `if startswith("Basic ") or startswith("basic ")` or `if test("^[Bb]asic ")`.